# Redirect to wrong page

Tags: php

Can anyone help me here? Thank you!
Issue: In Admin page, it redirect to Student Account when I access login page. It must be redirected to its own page(admin page).
role 1 = admin
role 2 = student account

```
//Session for admin page

if(!isset($_SESSION['role']) == 1){
    header("location: index.php");
    die();
}

//Session for student page

if(!isset($_SESSION['role']) == 2){
    header("location: index.php");
    die();
}
```

Comment: [isset](https://www.php.net/isset) only returns boolean `true` or `false`. It does not return the value of the variable if set. You need to do a separate comparison. Basic syntax. Manual is your friend.

Comment: Also, the `header` statements are identical regardless of the role. Not clear what you're trying to accomplish here. You may need to spell out your application logic in clear terms before writing it out.

Comment: Basic misunderstandings on `!` not operator and `isset()` has a code smell here (per @MarkusAO insights above, no need to repeat). Likely total lack of focus from OP on class assignment and ridiculous attempts thereafter as an attempt to have actual coding attempt here on SO (failure to do so).

Comment: @GetSet indeed. Code actually needs to be understood. Let's have `if(!isset($_SESSION['role']) == 1)` translated to plain language. It says: If session role is not isset (= notset), make a loose comparison of the result (true or false) to an integer (1 or 2). In a bool-int comparison, any non-zero integers evaluate as true.

Comment: Thus OP missed complete lecture on `&&` in an `if` condition. I hope I'm not being mean to point out that zero-interest in coding is not my problem. I suspect (but I could be wrong, some lectures do get missed no fault intended) that with this code sample and Google search available, ahhh... probably the former.

Comment: Well I spelled out an answer of sorts, of the educational type. Here's to hoping OP is keen on learning and understanding. Not sure if the conditional above is "code smell" or "attempt at magic". When I was a kid tinkering with BASIC on my sturdy MSX, I remember thinking I'd write a game, just like one of those I'd typed in from them books, and produced many lines of very cool looking statements. But alas it didn't run.  But I wasn't discouraged. 30 years down the road, I can actually produce something sensible.

Comment: You have a point @MarkusAO. I remember those days too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code actually needs to be understood.** Looking at your condition:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['role']) == 1)
```

...when translated to plain language, it reads:

```
if session role is not isset (= notset), 
make a loose comparison of the "notset" result (= true or false) 
with a positive integer (1 or 2).
```

This is clearly a nonsensical statement when "read out loud". You would have to separate your "is set" from your "is something" into two separate evaluations. (N.B. In a bool-to-integer comparison, any non-zero integers are coerced to boolean values and evaluate as true.)

Further, in your code, you redirect to the same `index.php` page, with no query parameters set, regardless of the outcome of your condition. This makes the conditional logic moot. You would have to redirect to unique destinations that reflect the result of your evaluation.

That said, you could for example do something like this instead:

```
// set a default role if none defined:
$_SESSION['role'] ??= 0;

// map roles to destinations:
$page = match($_SESSION['role']) {
    1 => 'admin.php',
    2 => 'student.php',
    default => 'index.php'
};

// goto where they should:
header("Location: {$page}");
exit;
```

No `isset` or other conditional evaluation. No code repetition. Easy to extend for future roles. Quite readable. (If you're not on PHP 8, use `switch` instead.)

Please take the time to **spell out to yourself** the intended application logic -- state it in plain language. See if what you're saying makes any sense. Then, when you code it out, understand the "*translation*" of the code you have written (or copied). Ensure that it matches your original "declaration" of the logic that should be executed.

When you gain more programming experience, you will "think in code" as your second language, and have little need to spell out "mental pseudo-code". For a beginner though, this practice is much recommended to ensure that you *produce sensible expressions*. Good luck and [don't forget your friend the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php). Familiarity with standard reference is not optional.